# No debuggable process with android studio 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to use the profiler, in android studio, I see my phone in the dropdown list but when I click on the phone, I got **"No debuggable process"**.

I use the **emulator Google Pixel 3a API 30x86**
I'm running the **debug build variant**
I check **"Use libusb backend"** on my settings
My minimum version is 26sdk and target 30

I'm running **Android 4.1.2 on Manjaro**

Im out of idea and I really need this profiler for my application...

Below my buildtype:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check if you selected debug build variant
then try this

```
   buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro
}}
```

Comment: just remove custom debug block

Comment: Nothing changes :/ with this way